# Counting value changes in a table column

Tags: sql, sqlite

Consider a sorted table (according to id). How to count number of changes of the values in  column 'value'? In the following example, the number of changes is 3 (10 to 20, 20 to 10, 10 to 30). Thx

```
id    value
 1      10
 2      10
 3      20
 4      20
 5      10
 6      30
 7      30
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if ids are sequential with no gaps...

```
Select count(*)
From table t1
   join table t2 
       on t2.id = t1.id + 1
where t2.value <> t1.value
```

else...

```
Select count(*)
From table t1
   join table t2 
       on t2.id = (Select min(id)
                   From table 
                   where id > t1.id)
where t2.value <> t1.value
```

Comment: This works great! Is there any way to add the 'counting process' as a separate column that can be shown together with the original data set? i.e. having a table with three columns  | id | value | count | and in each row the count  is up to date with the count so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can identify the changes by using a correlated subquery.  Then add them up.  A change occurs when the value is different from the previous value:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*,
             (select value
              from table t2
              where t2.id < t.id
              order by t2.id desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_value
      from table t
     ) t
where prev_value <> value;
```

Note that due to `prev_value` being `NULL` for the first row, this ignores that one.

If you can guarantee that the `id`s are sequential with no gaps, you can do this more efficiently with a join:

```
select count(*)
from table t join
     table tprev
     on t.id = tprev.id + 1
where t.value <> tprev.value;
```

Comment: I am little bit confused, what is table t2 and t, i I have only one input table?

Comment: @dousin . . . Those are table aliases, abbreviations given to tables that make it possible to do self-joins.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use this function: lead() over(). If you have, for example, this select:

```
select id, value
from youTable
where id <= 7
```

I find next value of "value" column with lead() function and I compare with the current one so :

```
select count(1) as number from
   (select lead(value) over(order by id) as nextValue, id, value
    from youTable
    where id <= 7) as tmp
where tmp.nextValue <> tmp.value
```

now, in number I have the numbers of changed value into "value" column